# Rails `redirect_to "/#{session[:user_id]}"` puts '#_=_' in my URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to a simple redirect in rails using `redirect_to "/#{session[:user_id]}"`. For some reason it's redirecting to something like: '/2#*=*'.  I can `User.find(session[:user_id])` just fine, so where are the extra characters coming from and how do I sanitize them (remove them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be much better using the Rails [path helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) -

```
redirect_to user_path(session[:user_id])
```

This of course considers you have a users path:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path: ""
```

The problem you'll have is because you're trying to render a naked link, I believe Rails will treat it as a `get` request, and consequently want to append any params to the URL for you (hence the `=`)

Comment: If I use `resources :users, path: ''` to get access tot he path helpers; does that replace: `match '/:id', :controller => :user, :action => :show, :via => :get`?

Comment: Yes it does replace, but only in the view

Comment: `match '/edit', :to => 'user#edit', :via => :get` and 
`resources :user, path: '', except: [:edit, :new]` get me the results I want using the url_helper, but the #_=_ is a Facebook OAuth insert.